# Retrieving Subscribers via C# SDK, results always empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, fuel-sdk

I am brand new to ExactTarget and their C# SDK/API.  I am having no luck on what should be the simplest of tasks.

I am trying to use the FuelSDK-CSharp objsamples project to simply retrieve a Subscriber.  The sample code in Sample_Subscriber.cs always returns empty response.Results when doing a Get.  I never receive a Subscriber.  I did realize I needed to add a SubscriberKey to each request.  The Post/Patch/Delete requests all work properly.  However, the Get request seems to succeed, but without returning data.  I have tried filtering on both EmailAddress and SubscriberKey.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!
-Kevin

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
        ET_Subscriber sub = new ET_Subscriber();
        sub.AuthStub = client;
        GetReturn response = sub.Get();
        foreach (ET_Subscriber subscriber in response.Results)
        {
            litResponse.Text = litResponse.Text + "EmailAddress: " + subscriber.EmailAddress + " Status: " + subscriber.Status.ToString() + "<br/>";
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Victor for the response.  

I just learned that the Get functionality works, just not on the data I was querying.  My test program creates a new Subscriber, and immediately tries to Get it using a filter.  This still fails.  

When I tried doing the Get without a filter it returned plenty of data.  I was able to filter on the pre-existing data, but not the records I have created.  

I am able to verify my Create works, because I can Update and Delete the records I create.  It seems to me that there is something in the create that prevents it from being found.